# Enforcing no hyphenation of the last word in the first line of Definition while keeping the line well-aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, theorems, hyphenation, ieeetran, ntheorem

I am using the IEEEtran theorem environment and `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]` to customize the definitions. Generally, I am satisfied with its output:

[image: ReachableRead]

However, for another definition followed by a long word (i.e., PrecedingWrite here), it splits the word (as Preceding-Write):

[image: PrecedingWrite without mbox]

I can use `\mbox{PrecedingWrite}` to enforce its "integrity". But the first line of this definition becomes ill-aligned.

[image: PrecedingWrite with mbox]

Therefore,

> How to both enforce the "integrity" of the word "PrecedingWrite" and keep the first line well-aligned? (To this end, you can break the first line. However, I don't want a global `\newline` option.) Great thanks.

---

*An illustrating Code for the second figure above:*

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\begin{document}
    \begin{definition}[\textsl{PrecedingWrite (PW)}] \label{def:precedingwrite}
      \textsl{PrecedingWrite} is a matrix such that for each operation
      $o$ and each variable $v$, the entry $\textsl{PW}[o][v] = w$ if and only if
    \end{definition}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: You probably want this automated... but why not just leave such things to the end and then fix the odd ones here-and-there (if any) manually?

Comment: @Werner I just need to fix *this* definition. So manual methods are OK.

Comment: I don't understand why you just use `\newline` or ``\\`` then? I mention this since you say "I don't want a global `\newline` option" yet also mention "manual methods are OK".

Comment: @Werner I don't want a global `\newline` option for the whole Definition environment, because I want to leave other definitions (such as Definition 5.3) the same (i.e., no break line after `Definition 5.3 (ReachableRead(RR))`). I just need to fix Definition 5.4. Therefore, I want to do this locally. Sorry for the vagueness. I am not very familiar with this topic. BTW, the `\hfill` + `a blank line` method works for me, as suggested in the answer by @Przemysław Scherwentke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But IEEEtran automates the procedure that you described. An example is with some other words, but the result should be visible in the second definition: the first line filled with glue.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\begin{document}


\section{}

    \begin{definition}[\textsl{PrecedingWrite (PW)}] \label{def:precedingwrite}
      \textsl{PrecedingWrite} is a matrix such that for each operation
      $o$ and each variable $v$, the entry $\textsl{PW}[o][v] = w$ if and only if
    \end{definition}

 \begin{definition}[\textsl{LongPrecedingWrite (LPW)}] \label{def:precedingwrite}
      \textsl{LongPrecedingWrite} is a matrix such that for each operation
      $o$ and each variable $v$, the entry $\textsl{PW}[o][v] = w$ if and only if
    \end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If such a result is not done automatically, you can always (from the comments I can deduce, that it is done once) force a new line e.g. in the following way:

```
\begin{definition}[\textsl{PrecedingWrite (PW)}] \label{def:precedingwrite}\hfill

      \textsl{PrecedingWrite} is a matrix such that for each operation
      $o$ and each variable $v$, the entry $\textsl{PW}[o][v] = w$ if and only if
    \end{definition}
```

Comment: The last method works in my case. I have tried `\hfill` before but missed the blank line followed. Thanks.